# How can Findbugs detect empty catch block?

Tags: findbugs

I hope to detect empty catch block below with Findbugs

Are there any default Findbugs checker for this?

I cannot find ....

```
} catch (RemoteException re) {
    /* ignore */
} catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
    ;
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

If I should make custom checkers, how can I do this?

Could you let me get some guides for that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think FindBugs has a built-in check for this as I don't see warnings about it if I create an empty catch block. However, [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) has the [`EmptyBlock`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html#EmptyBlock) check which can be applied individually to every type of block: `try`, `catch`, `if`, `else`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with java byte code, in that you can't always ascertain the end of a catch block, and so in general this test can't be done 100% in FindBugs.

An example is, if the only exit out of a try block is a return statement, and there are no following catch blocks, or finally blocks.

Answer (score 0):

FindBugs doesn't have the implementation of detector for this.You can check what detectors Findbugs has by right clicking Project,and selecting properties -> Findbugs -> Detector configuration.

But You can make yourself detector to detect this bug.Or use other tools ,like CodePro Analysis,PMD.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests "FindBugs" it only looks for the bugs in the source code, like if there is any line of code that may potentially cause SQL Injection. It doesn't account for any best practices. CheckStyle is the best API for identifying empty catch blocks or even not throwing exception and catching them.